# Get height based on fixed width UIImageView image

Tags: objective-c, uiimageview, uiimage, height, image-resizing

How can I get height for UIImageView based on fixed (310.0f) UIImageView width for real looking image ?

So the thing should work for placing UIImageViews in UITableViewCells (thats not important for question). But I want to point on some examples: 9gag app, facebook, google+ and other feeds with images that resize and are put in UITableViewCell

Comment: Actually its downsizing image to 310.0f width and then based on that width, its good quality image, corresponding height.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Divide the width you want by the actual width of the image. Then multiple that number with the actual height.

```
UIImage* image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"someImage.png"];
CGSize imageSize = image.size;
CGFloat newHeight = (310.0 / imageSize.width) * imageSize.height;
```